# Python Selenium: Link click not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have following HTML, I want to click the `a` tag with text `MOUNT TAMALPAIS SP, CA` the `href` is actually a javascript method. Below are details:

**Code**

```
keyword = 'MOUNT TAMALPAIS SP'    
link_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, keyword)))
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="facilities_suggestions_list" class="suggestions_list">
   <h3>Experience</h3>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120063:-122.595:37.9038889::CA&quot;, &quot;120063&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120063"><strong>MOUNT</strong> <strong>TAMALPAIS</strong> <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120061:-121.93:37.8627778::CA&quot;, &quot;120061&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120061"><strong>MT.</strong> DIABLO <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120062:-116.675:33.8102778::CA&quot;, &quot;120062&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120062"><strong>MT.</strong> SAN JACINTO <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;NRSO:70045:-106.2227778:38.7141667::CO&quot;, &quot;70045&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_70045"><strong>MOUNT</strong> PRINCETON <span>, CO</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;NRSO:70124:-111.6036111:40.4061111::UT&quot;, &quot;70124&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_70124"><strong>MT.</strong> TIMPANOGOS <span>, UT</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281003:-81.2802778:29.8772222::FL&quot;, &quot;281003&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281003">ANASTASIA <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120013:-122.3022222:37.2227778::CA&quot;, &quot;120013&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120013">BUTANO <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;NE:230042:-103.0197222:42.7091667::NE&quot;, &quot;230042&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_230042">Chadron <strong>SP</strong> <span>, NE</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120035:-120.065:34.4622222::CA&quot;, &quot;120035&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120035">GAVIOTA <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120048:-121.5694444:36.0530556::CA&quot;, &quot;120048&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120048">LIMEKILN <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120049:-123.7925:39.4933333::CA&quot;, &quot;120049&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120049">MACKERRICHER <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120052:-123.7113889:38.9738889::CA&quot;, &quot;120052&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120052">MANCHESTER <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281060:-82.6033333:29.9194444::FL&quot;, &quot;281060&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281060">OLENO <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;NE:230143:-96.7172222:42.6097222::NE&quot;, &quot;230143&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_230143">Ponca <strong>SP</strong> <span>, NE</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281076:-81.0836111:29.3408333::FL&quot;, &quot;281076&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281076">TOMOKA <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281077:-84.9505556:30.5697222::FL&quot;, &quot;281077&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281077">TORREYA <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120097:-123.7733333:39.2763889::CA&quot;, &quot;120097&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120097">VANDAMME <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;NRSO:71897:-131.8988889:56.6441667::AK&quot;, &quot;71897&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_71897"><strong>MOUNT</strong> FLEMER CABIN <span>, AK</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;NRSO:75021:-82.7566667:35.4027778::NC&quot;, &quot;75021&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_75021"><strong>MOUNT</strong> PISGAH CAMPGROUND <span>, NC</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;NRSO:70459:-119.8973611:39.3122778::CA&quot;, &quot;70459&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_70459"><strong>MOUNT</strong> ROSE (NV) <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;NRSO:71896:-132.2391667:56.6644444::AK&quot;, &quot;71896&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_71896"><strong>MOUNT</strong> RYNDA CABIN <span>, AK</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120003:-122.4308333:37.8641667::CA&quot;, &quot;120003&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120003">ANGEL ISLAND <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281005:-81.2741667:24.6597222::FL&quot;, &quot;281005&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281005">BAHIA HONDA <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281128:-87.4038889:30.3180556::FL&quot;, &quot;281128&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281128">BIG LAGOON <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281008:-86.8783333:30.7116667::FL&quot;, &quot;281008&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281008">BLACKWATER RIVER <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281101:-81.3338889:28.9508333::FL&quot;, &quot;281101&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281101">Blue Spring <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281010:-82.8197222:28.0311111::FL&quot;, &quot;281010&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281010">CALADESI ISLAND <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120016:-122.3505556:41.1711111::CA&quot;, &quot;120016&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120016">CASTLE CRAGS <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120017:-121.1866667:37.6933333::CA&quot;, &quot;120017&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120017">CASWELL MEMORIAL <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281127:-82.2452778:26.6858333::FL&quot;, &quot;281127&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281127">CAYO COSTA <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120018:-122.4605556:38.0008333::CA&quot;, &quot;120018&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120018">CHINA CAMP <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:124900::::CA&quot;, &quot;124900&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_124900">CHINO HILLS <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120019:-122.8141667:39.0066667::CA&quot;, &quot;120019&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120019">CLEAR LAKE <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281013:-81.5913889:25.9916667::FL&quot;, &quot;281013&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281013">COLLIER-SEMINOLE <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281228:-80.985:24.7422222::FL&quot;, &quot;281228&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281228">CURRY HAMMOCK <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120023:-116.5616667:32.9358333::CA&quot;, &quot;120023&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120023">CUYAMACA RANCHO <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120029:-120.2419444:39.32::CA&quot;, &quot;120029&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120029">DONNER MEMORIAL <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120031:-120.0930556:38.9544444::CA&quot;, &quot;120031&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120031">EMERALD BAY <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281021:-85.5288889:30.7308333::FL&quot;, &quot;281021&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281021">FALLING WATERS <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281241:-82.9347222:29.5861111::FL&quot;, &quot;281241&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281241">FANNING SPRINGS <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281022:-81.2686111:29.6675::FL&quot;, &quot;281022&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281022">FAVER-DYKES <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281025:-85.2133333:30.8088889::FL&quot;, &quot;281025&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281025">FLORIDA CAVERNS <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281027:-81.4347222:30.67::FL&quot;, &quot;281027&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281027">FORT CLINCH <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;NE:230077:-103.4941667:42.6866667::NE&quot;, &quot;230077&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_230077">Fort Robinson <strong>SP</strong> <span>, NE</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120209:-121.5013889:36.7608333::CA&quot;, &quot;120209&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120209">FREMONT PEAK <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281033:-86.1566667:30.3294444::FL&quot;, &quot;281033&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281033">GRAYTON BEACH <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281186:-86.4466667:30.3852778::FL&quot;, &quot;281186&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281186">HENDERSON BEACH <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120040:-123.485:39.085::CA&quot;, &quot;120040&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120040">HENDY WOODS <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281036:-81.5305556:27.4711111::FL&quot;, &quot;281036&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281036">HIGHLANDS HAMMOCK <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="facility_suggestion"><a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;FL:281037:-82.2269444:28.1430556::FL&quot;, &quot;281037&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_281037">HILLSBOROUGH RIVER <strong>SP</strong> <span>, FL</span></a>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

The link of function is given here: http://pastebin.com/tfny2xdJ

Comment: Does this `link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[.=keyword]")))` works?

Comment: 'MOUNT TAMALPAIS SP' isn't your search keywords. Get source code with selenium and check which values can be returned. Search all links of page for printing contained text pattern. Different encoding pattern got different results, so be careful on decoding..

Comment: @Andersson No and most prolly because `<a`> contains `<strong>` as well?

Comment: @dsgdfg Yeah, the HTML is `<a href="javascript:UnifSearchEngine.selectResolvedAddress(&quot;CA:120063:-122.595:37.9038889::CA&quot;, &quot;120063&quot;, 1 )" id="suggestion_1_120063"><strong>MOUNT</strong> <strong>TAMALPAIS</strong> <strong>SP</strong> <span>, CA</span></a>`

Comment: @Volatil3, no, this shouldn't be a problem... Is there any exceptions?

Comment: @Andersson yeah weird `<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException'>` on the line.

Comment: Can you work with html codes, but need scan whole links with text if using a native searching methods. You can't  define any  link text variable if talking about web_page_automation. Another point you can't get data if a element not registered in CSS class(Like javascript output).

Comment: @Volatil3, it's  normal if you use `WebdriverWait`... Do you get `NoSuchElementException` if to use just `driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(keyword)` without explicit wait?

Comment: @Andersson without that I get no error at all. It just simply does not click and exit

Comment: @Andersson Question updated with link of code: http://pastebin.com/tfny2xdJ

Comment: @dsgdfg so what's the solution? I also have shared the code: http://pastebin.com/tfny2xdJ

Comment: @Volatil3, actually `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, keyword))).click()` works fine for me

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot click link using `click()` method, try following code instead:

```
keyword = 'MOUNT TAMALPAIS SP'    
link_text = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, keyword)))    
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', link_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The text is actually divided between 4 different child elements of the `<a>` tag you are trying to click. You can use `xpath` to get it base on all the text in the child elements

```
keyword = 'MOUNT TAMALPAIS SP, CA'
keywords = keyword.split(' ')
link_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[strong[contains(text(), "' + keywords[0] + '")] and strong[contains(text(), "' + keywords[1] + '")] and strong[contains(text(), "' + keywords[2] + '")] and span[contains(text(), "' + keywords[3] + '")]]')))
```